# How do I connect this parent table with its different children tables?

Tags: sql, roles, multiple-tables

I'm working on an application which has different types of users i.e. students, tutors, and administrators. However, I initially set up my database to have only two tables: Users (that holds all the login information, common to all types) and Profiles (that holds all other information; though each column applies to a certain type of user).

I was thinking maybe I should have Users, and 3 separate tables for each type i.e. Students, Tutors, and Administrators. However, how do I link those three tables with Users table? I'm sure there would be a bridge table but I'm not too sure how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be a solid starting point for you. Define the tables which it sounds like you are ok with, then apply the relationships using the ALTER TABLE command. See below.

```
CREATE TABLE Users
(
ID INT IDENTITY (1,1),
PRIMARY KEY (ID),
UserName VARCHAR(20),
Password VARCHAR(20)
)

CREATE TABLE Students
(
ID INT IDENTITY (1,1),
PRIMARY KEY (ID),
UserID INT --foreign key to Users.ID column
--Other columns
)

CREATE TABLE Tutors
(
ID INT IDENTITY (1,1),
PRIMARY KEY (ID),
UserID INT --foreign key to Users.ID column
--Other columns
)

CREATE TABLE Administrators
(
ID INT IDENTITY (1,1),
PRIMARY KEY (ID),
UserID INT --foreign key to Users.ID column
--Other columns
)
--Apply foreign key relationships
ALTER TABLE Students
ADD FOREIGN KEY (UserID)
REFERENCES Users(ID)

ALTER TABLE Tutors
ADD FOREIGN KEY (UserID)
REFERENCES Users(ID)

ALTER TABLE Administrators
ADD FOREIGN KEY (UserID)
REFERENCES Users(ID)
```

Answer (score 1):

You would add the primary key of the Users table as a foreign key to each of the 3 seperate tables.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

1. `USER_TYPE` table, containing `userType` and `userTypeID` columns.
2. `USER` table, containing `userID` column *plus* login information, *plus* a `userTypeID` column, linking to `USER_TYPE` table.
3. `USER_STUDENT` table, containing student related columns, *plus* a `userID` column, linking to the `USER` table.
4. `USER_TUTOR` table, containing tutor related columns, *plus* a `userID` column, linking to the `USER` table.
5. `USER_ADMINISTRATOR` table, containing administrator related columns, *plus* a `userID` column, linking to the `USER` table.

You can JOIN 1, 2 and {3 or 4 or 5} tables as shown below, and in similar other ways:

```
SELECT U.*, S.*
FROM USER as U
     INNER JOIN USER_TYPE AS UT ON UT.userTypeID = U.userTypeID
     INNER JOIN USER_STUDENT AS US ON US.userID = U.userID
WHERE UT.userType = 'STUDENT'
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to introduce a "role" table that defines the type of roles/profiles in your system (student, admin, tutor, ...), then add a mapping table "user_role" which maps users to roles (ie John is both a student and a teacher implies two records in the "user_role" table. Role-specific information for a user can be in the tables shown as "detail" tables below.

```
    USER
    ----
    user_id
    username
    password

    ROLE
    ----
    role_id
    role_name

    USER_ROLE
    ----------
    user_role_id
    user_id
    role_id
    from_date
    to_date

    STUDENT_DETAIL
    --------------
    user_role_id
    student_number

    TUTOR_DETAIL
    ------------
    user_role_id
    sin
```